# Mapping 1 command to multiple key combinations in vim

Tags: vim

Im using nerdtree plugin in vim.
With let `NERDTreeMapActivateNode="<Right>"` a tree node opens up bs using the **right arrow** key.
But I want also the **left arrow** key do the same. Is that even possible that 2 Keymappings can do the same thing? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible to have a single command mapped to many key sequences:

```
nnoremap a diw
nnoremap b diw
nnoremap c diw
```

But this is a special case, where the mapping is done internally by a plugin and it is arbitrarily limited to one.

[Apparently](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/81f3eaba295b3fceb2d032db57e5eae99ae480f8/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim#L327), the plugin sets the filetype of its buffer as `nerdtree`, so you *might* be able to deal with this in an agnostic way by mapping `<Left>` to `<Right>` only in the desired context:

```
" after/ftplugin/nerdtree.vim (relative to your `.vim` or `vimfiles`)
nmap <buffer> <Left> <Right>
```

But a better solution would probably be to use the plugin's own [`:help NERDTreeKeymapAPI`](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt#L1336).

Comment: I've just discovered [this](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1280) D:

Comment: Yeah, **HELP WANTED**. But the plugin presumably still works so people can still use it. I still use Snipmate more than 10 years after its last commit ;-).

Answer (score 1):

created a file ~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/mymapping.vim

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({                                                                                                                                              
    \ 'key': '<Left>',                                                                                                                                     
    \ 'callback': 'FunctionLEFTkey',
    \ 'quickhelpText': 'echo full path of current node',                                                                                                   
            \ 'scope': 'DirNode' })

function! FunctionLEFTkey(dummy_node_arg_required_cozof_scope)
    execute 'normal' g:NERDTreeMapActivateNode                                                                                                                    
endfunction                                                                                                                                                          

call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({                                                                                                                                              
    \ 'key': '<Right>',                                                                                                                                    
    \ 'callback': 'FunctionRIGHTkey',                                                                                                                      
    \ 'quickhelpText': 'echo full path of current node',                                                                                                   
    \ 'scope': 'all' })                                                                                                                                    

function! FunctionRIGHTkey()                                                                                                                                          
    execute 'normal' g:NERDTreeMapActivateNode                                                                                                                    
endfunction
```

- Pressing Leftarrow in nerdtree closes or opens a directory node.
- Pressing Rightarrow in nerdtree closes or open a directory or opens a
  file.

Works as long ***NERDTreeMapActivateNode*** (in vimrc) isn't set to Leftarrow or Rightarrow key because then only this key can toggle *NERDTreeMapActivateNode* and *NERDTreeAddKeyMap* doesn't work anymore.